# Setting Up Logins For Users with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to use Django's built in user authentication for login/allowing users to create an account and login. I think there's something wrong with my urls or where files are placed in the project. Can anyone help?

I know the login.html file is supposed to be inside a folder called 'registration.' I think the fact that my templates are then in a sub folder called 'capstone' might be causing issues. I just don't know how to point to the right file when someone clicks to login.

In urls.py under 'weather' I have the following. In two tutorials I saw it should say 'accounts/' but I'm a bit confused as to why.

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('capstone.urls')), # medium site says to do this
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is how my files are set up in Visual Studio Code:

[image: description]

[image]

Now under weather, I have:

[image]

Now under urls.py under capstone, I have:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'locations', views.LocationViewSet)

urlpatterns = [


    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), 
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', 
    namespace='rest_framework')),
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "capstone/home.html")


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, 
password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            return render(request, "capstone/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid email and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "capstone/login.html")    


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation - this part works!
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "capstone/signup.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            User = get_user_model()
            user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, 
password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print(e)
            return render(request, "capstone/signup.html", {
                "message": "Email address already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))
    else:
        return render(request, "capstone/signup.html")
```

Comment: You should join them in your settings.py pathway...Also don't forget to add emails for your passwords...that doesn't come standard in django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the path to `accounts/` allows you to create a url such as `<your_site_name>/accounts/login`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Basicaly the link shows you get the `login/`, `logout/`, and a bunch other urls/views for free. You can append names to the url making it longer if you would like...

Now Im not sure which app the url_conf is in, that calls `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),` but I'm guessing since you have the static_dir addition at the bottom, its the `weather/settings.py` urls conf.

In settings.py in the TEMPLATES settings. If APP_DIRS is True, (which is by default), Django will check the template directory which is inside app directory that the template is being called in. In your case, it will check the template directory in the `weather` app (which is your main app). You would need to change your directory heiarchy.
Using **django.contrib.auth** urls

```
weather
|
|--templates
      |
      |--registration
            |
            |--login.html
```

If you want to use the capstone app. Then you need to move the call
`path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` to the capstone app. At which point the URL will change to `<your_site_name/capstone/accounts/login>`.

=============================
Now you have a `login_view` instead, named *login* which is overriding the login view of django contrib, so your heirachy should resemble something like this.

```
capstone
|
|--templates
    |
     |--capstone
          |
          | -- login.html
```

Also FYI make sure to end your paths to the URL’s with “/“. Like “login” should be “login/“

Comment: Thank you that was helpful! I appreciate the detailed answer. I'm a bit confused still - I edited my post, showing what I have now. My weather app looks the same as your directory hierarchy, and I moved the path to the capstone app. I'm still getting 'TemplateDoesNotExist at /login" error.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback and Error messages from Django? It will say which view is raising the error. Also display your views.py. I think it has something to do with the fact you have URLs now with the same name as Django contrib. `name=login`. If you want to use a separate view for logging in you need to namespace them, otherwise just remove that url. You can provide a template to login without overriding the views, which is what I originally thought you wanted.

Comment: I put the views.py in the original post. To be honest I'm sure my urls could be cleaned up a lot. I am very new to this. Most projects I've done in Django for classes have had the login/logout views and urls done for you already, and the projects focused on creating other things, so that's why I wanted to try to do it myself this time. Here's the traceback: https://dpaste.com/7VQQ4DATA

Comment: The error in the traceback is raised because of your login_view. Line 44-45. See my edit at the bottom.